# A completely simple semigroup with cancelation is a group (simple proof)

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Is there a simple proof of the following fact:

**Fact**. Let $S$ be a completely simple semigroup with cancellations, i.e. each of the equalities $xa=xb$, $ax=bx$ implies $a=b$. Prove that $S$ is a group.

Using Sushkevich-Rees Theorem, I can prove it, but my proof is not elegant.

Can you prove this fact using only simple arguments? Probably, you know a paper, where this result was proved at the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A completely simple semigroup has by definition a (primitive) idempotent $e$ and $SxS=S$ for all $x\in S$.  If $x\in S$, then $eex=ex$ and so $ex=x$ and similarly, we see that $e$ is a right identity.  Thus $S$ is a monoid and the identity is the unique idempotent of $S$.  Let us write $1$ for the identity.    Let $x\in S$.  Then $uxy=1$ for some $u,y$ by simplicity.  Then $xyuxyu=xyu$ and so $xyu=1$ as $1$ is the unique idempotent.  Similarly, $yuxyux=yux$ and hence $yux=1$ because each idempotent is the identity.  Thus $x$ is invertible with inverse $yu$. So $S$ is a group.

Comment: I simplified the argument getting rid of the bicyclic monoid. Now it is elementary and works for simple cancellative semigroups with an idempotent.

Comment: A simple semigroup with cancellations is not necessarily a group?

Comment: @MarkSapir, no.  See Trotter, P. G.
Cancellative simple semigroups and groups. 
Semigroup Forum 14 (1977), no. 3, 189–198. They do not even have to embed in groups

Comment: OK. Thank you !